# How to determine if current locale has 24-hour or 12-hour time format in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time, format, locale

This seems like a dumb question, but I've read the docs and couldn't find any straight-forward method.

I did something awful like:

```
$isTwentyFourByLocale = (substr(strftime('%X', mktime(16, 0, 0, 6, 15, 2010)), 0, 2) == 16);
```

Which works, but isn't there any better, straight-forward way?

Comment: Just curious: For what do you need the information?

Comment: Your solution is not *awful*, I kinda like it, should be pretty safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your approach, it can be done shorter:

```
$isTwentyFourByLocale = (substr(gmstrftime('%X', 57600), 0, 2) == 16);
```